Transparently Routing Traffic Through Tor
I followed this Transparently Routing Traffic Through Tor example the section of Local Redirection Through Tor with iptables.
It works well. Now my goal is to above example to exclude specific user (-m owner --uid-owner user) to use clearnet internet, (real IP not TOR).
My goal is the same with TAILS OS, I want entire debian system running with tor but I exclude unsafe browser to run with real IP.
How can I do that?
Update 3-10-2024!
I post information for iptables firewall rules
### Set variables
# The UID that Tor runs as (varies from system to system)

_tor_uid=`id -u debian-tor` #Debian/Ubuntu
_tor_uid2=`id -u username`

# Tor's TransPort
_trans_port="9040"

# Tor's DNSPort
_dns_port="5353"

# Tor's VirtualAddrNetworkIPv4
_virt_addr="10.192.0.0/10"

# Your outgoing interface
_out_if="enp35s0"

# LAN destinations that shouldn't be routed through Tor
_non_tor="127.0.0.0/8 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16"

# Other IANA reserved blocks (These are not processed by tor and dropped by default)
_resv_iana="0.0.0.0/8 100.64.0.0/10 169.254.0.0/16 192.0.0.0/24 192.0.2.0/24 192.88.99.0/24 198.18.0.0/15 198.51.100.0/24 203.0.113.0/24 224.0.0.0/4 240.0.0.0/4 255.255.255.255/32"

### Don't lock yourself out after the flush
#iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
#iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

### Flush iptables
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F

### *nat OUTPUT (For local redirection)
# nat .onion addresses
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d $_virt_addr -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j REDIRECT --to-ports $_trans_port

# nat dns requests to Tor
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports $_dns_port

# Don't nat the Tor process, the loopback, or the local network
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner $_tor_uid -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -j RETURN

# Don't nat the Tor process, the loopback, or the local network 
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner $_tor_uid2 -j RETURN

# Allow lan access for hosts in $_non_tor
for _lan in $_non_tor; do
  iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d $_lan -j RETURN
done

for _iana in $_resv_iana; do
  iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d $_iana -j RETURN
done

# Redirect all other pre-routing and output to Tor's TransPort
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j REDIRECT --to-ports $_trans_port

### *filter INPUT
# Don't forget to grant yourself ssh access from remote machines before the DROP.
#iptables -A INPUT -i $_out_if -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow INPUT from lan hosts in $_non_tor
# Uncomment these 3 lines to enable.
#for _lan in $_non_tor; do
# iptables -A INPUT -s $_lan -j ACCEPT
#done

# Log & Drop everything else. Uncomment to enable logging
#iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "Dropped INPUT packet: " --log-level 7 --log-uid
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP

### *filter FORWARD
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP

### *filter OUTPUT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow Tor process output
iptables -A OUTPUT -o $_out_if -m owner --uid-owner $_tor_uid -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -o $_out_if -m owner --uid-owner $_tor_uid2 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

# Allow loopback output
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Tor transproxy magic
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport $_trans_port --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j ACCEPT

# Allow OUTPUT to lan hosts in $_non_tor
# Uncomment these 3 lines to enable.
#for _lan in $_non_tor; do
# iptables -A OUTPUT -d $_lan -j ACCEPT
#done

# Log & Drop everything else. Uncomment to enable logging
#iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "Dropped OUTPUT packet: " --log-level 7 --log-uid
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP

### Set default policies to DROP
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP


Duplicate the line
# Allow Tor process output
iptables -A OUTPUT -o $_out_if -m owner --uid-owner $_tor_uid -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

and the line
# Don't nat the Tor process, the loopback, or the local network
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner $_tor_uid -j RETURN

for the UID you want to bypass, but be warned: it can lead to the leaks! Use QubesOS for proper insulation and forget the Tails(hit)
UPDATE: firewall rules :
### Set variables
# The UID that Tor runs as (varies from system to system)

_tor_uid=`id -u debian-tor` #Debian/Ubuntu
_tor_uid2=`id -u username`

# Tor's TransPort
_trans_port="9040"

# Tor's DNSPort
_dns_port="5353"

# Tor's VirtualAddrNetworkIPv4
_virt_addr="10.192.0.0/10"

# Your outgoing interface
_out_if="enp35s0"

# LAN destinations that shouldn't be routed through Tor
_non_tor="127.0.0.0/8 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16"

# Other IANA reserved blocks (These are not processed by tor and dropped by default)
_resv_iana="0.0.0.0/8 100.64.0.0/10 169.254.0.0/16 192.0.0.0/24 192.0.2.0/24 192.88.99.0/24 198.18.0.0/15 198.51.100.0/24 203.0.113.0/24 224.0.0.0/4 240.0.0.0/4 255.255.255.255/32"

### Don't lock yourself out after the flush
#iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
#iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

### Flush iptables
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F

### *nat OUTPUT (For local redirection)
# nat .onion addresses
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d $_virt_addr -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j REDIRECT --to-ports $_trans_port

# nat dns requests to Tor
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports $_dns_port

# Don't nat the Tor process, the loopback, or the local network
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner $_tor_uid -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner $_tor_uid2 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -j RETURN

# Allow lan access for hosts in $_non_tor
for _lan in $_non_tor; do
  iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d $_lan -j RETURN
done

for _iana in $_resv_iana; do
  iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d $_iana -j RETURN
done

# Redirect all other pre-routing and output to Tor's TransPort
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j REDIRECT --to-ports $_trans_port

### *filter INPUT
# Don't forget to grant yourself ssh access from remote machines before the DROP.
#iptables -A INPUT -i $_out_if -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow INPUT from lan hosts in $_non_tor
# Uncomment these 3 lines to enable.
#for _lan in $_non_tor; do
# iptables -A INPUT -s $_lan -j ACCEPT
#done

# Log & Drop everything else. Uncomment to enable logging
#iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "Dropped INPUT packet: " --log-level 7 --log-uid
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP

### *filter FORWARD
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP

### *filter OUTPUT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow Tor process output
iptables -A OUTPUT -o $_out_if -m owner --uid-owner $_tor_uid -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -o $_out_if -m owner --uid-owner $_tor_uid2 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

# Allow loopback output
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Tor transproxy magic
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport $_trans_port --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j ACCEPT

# Allow OUTPUT to lan hosts in $_non_tor
# Uncomment these 3 lines to enable.
#for _lan in $_non_tor; do
# iptables -A OUTPUT -d $_lan -j ACCEPT
#done

# Log & Drop everything else. Uncomment to enable logging
#iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "Dropped OUTPUT packet: " --log-level 7 --log-uid
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP

### Set default policies to DROP
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP


Vensin Thank you for helping, but It doesn't work I made _tor_uid2=id -u username` and put your line...

have you put the uid2 line right after the original one? before routing all the rest through Tor? Rules order matters!

I put your line first. The same result. It doesn't work, Are you sure that your line is correct? Please check my setup here and tell my where is correct to put your line, the section Local Redirection Through Tor example with iptables.Thanks

also you need to make a duplicate near " Don't nat the Tor process, the loopback, or the local network". Basically - as I'm doing it - make a for loop at every place where tor_uid is in the rules and it will duplicate the lines. I'll update my answer because it looks like I missed that point initially

We have progress but not desired results. So I put both your lines after the same lines from original script from the gitlab. We have two problems. All my debian machine run ISP IP and DNS work with TOR.  I want O N L Y to load firefox  with my ISP sudo -u username -H firefox and all other system through TOR. I think we need some more rules....

well, it is already working as you want. If you have set the global DNS through Tor - it will use Tor. In firefox use DoH - DNS over HTTPS, set it in settings tab and use SOCKS5, not SOCKS5S if you want your firefox's DNS requests to slip over Tor. But - frequently speaking - rise a local BIND server without any forwarders and enforce DNSSec, this will set the things right

It doesn't work Alexey. Do you know TAIL OS ? Probably not. Tails OS works all operanting system ONLY with tor, everything all ports all protocols. The only app that use clearnet internet is "unsafe broser (firefox)". So the script that is the link in my question Transparently Routing Traffic Through Tor all my debian operating system with success. So I want one or more rules to exclude username to start firefox with clearnet internet. The same thing with TAIL OS. I appreciate your help and your time but both lines not work, because now all debian works with clearnet ISP IP.

Tails OS is buggy and immature, QubesOS is a way better. The setup with these two lines must exclude tor user and the one you're specifying. How are you checking that it's fails to do so? In the link for a script you've posted - basically - you're adding uid-containing lines for all the uids you need to exclude and that's it. Attach your current firewall script so I can take a deeper look

try use my rules. Looks like you have the rule order messed up - it matters for any firewall

Nothing. The same result. It is not working Alexey. Did you try your example? curl ifconfg.me the result show my ISP IP. Normaly with your setup must show TOR IP. Second bug I load firefox with user id username and without username and both show me ISP IP with TOR dns. It doesn't work. All apps work with ISP IP and dns with TOR . I didn't want this result. I am sorry.

is it showing not your ISP IP being launched from Tor user? I told you about DNS - you better do as I say, because Tor's DNS can be messed up with exit point's DNS resolver "tricks". Leave only dot-onion domains for Tor DNS - it's routed through the ISC BIND config

I am sorry, It has stuck the mind in your opinion. From terminal I type curl ifconfig.me  -->>> AND SHOW ME THE ISP IP.  <<<--- Do you understand? How many times  I have to say to you to understand it??  If your two lines are correct the command curl ifconfig.me MUST show TOR IP. Forget the DNS as you stuck with that. The only thing you succeeded with the two lines is to work only ISP IP whole system with TOR DNS . I told you a lot of times . I don't want this scenario. I would ISP IP with ISP DNS O N L Y When I load an app with specific user that exclude from TOR Thank you for trying.

the user you're logged in from - is it the user added to excludes?

Vensnin I am apologize that I delay to answer to you. Yest of course. The same user that exclude from iptables firewall rules. So which is the problem Alexey?

I will try to make a stand setup to check next week. And if you're logging in as debian-tor user - it's your ISP IP? that's how it should be: both this new user and debian-tor are excluded from being routed through Tor. Try making one more user and log in from it and check - you should see Tor IP

I created second user as you said. So I login in my linux machine with user A and exlude the user B then debian-tor user works as TOR. So now works fine I think. I recently Installed wireshark then I watch for dns leaks. I think it is impossible to have dns leaks. All linux machine works 127.0.0.1 port 53 as dns. I would like to ask you if I want to exlude from TOR IP AND TOR dns the transmission app ,is it possible that? Thank you Alexey.

It's possible - just run the app from separate user account and be just fine: you can use exclusion rules that are based on users not just as a real users - but also for apps
